# My website mess up with browser resize

Tags: html, css, web

Below is an ideal look of my website
http://i44.tinypic.com/jayyhu.jpg

but it doesn't look the same in all computers. I checked it with browsershots . org and my website mess up in almost all browsers. It even mess up when i resize my browser.

Perhaps it's because I don't get a horizontal scroll on browser resize. Please suggest me some ways to fix it.

My website url is
http://come2chat.x10host.com

if it doesn't open then please refresh the window. I am using a free webhost during the development period and so it's not reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the biggest problem is that you are using margins and paddings to center the content in the screen and it makes everything more difficult.

Instead, create a wrapping `div` and set `margin: 0 auto;` to it.

I made this small change in your page, you can check it here:

http://www.radiogramola.cat/stack/u.html

I only added two div with class "wrapper" and some CSS resets. You can check the code.

---

Then, you should decide which kind of layout you want to create:

- **Fixed**: like stackoverflow.com, when the user resize the window, the page does not change.
- **Fluid**: like wikipedia.org, it expands occupying all the available space and adapts itself to the browser size.
- **Responsive**: like css-tricks.com, it changes the layout depending on the browser size.

You can view this video with a visual explanation:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/whats-the-difference-between-fixed-fluid-adaptive-and-responsive-web-design-treehouse

Depending on your decision, your next steps will be different.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your layout. You have fixed widths and heights in pixels.
When you resize window, they will stick to their heights and widths and wont resize accordingly. So content overlaps or jumps.

Fix everything in percentage. That is the best you can get.

Im putting up a demo below.

```
<body id="library">


        <div id="body">

            <div id="sidebar"></div>

            <div id="content">

                <div id="navbar"></div>

                <div id="contentwindow"></div>

            </div>

        </div>


</body>
```

css

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#library {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#library #body {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 3% 5%;
}
#library #body #sidebar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: #8eeeff;
  margin: 2%;
}
#library #body #content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 2%;
}
#library #body #content #navbar {
  width: 90%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 3% 5%;
}
#library #body #content #contentwindow {
  width: 90%;
  height: 70%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 3% 5%;
}
```

run this and resize your window.